# Evaluate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)dx}{x^2+a^2}$ using contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

This question is Exercise 10 of Chapter 3 of Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis.

> Show that if $a>0$, then
>
> $$\int_0^{\infty}  \frac{\log(x)dx}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{\pi \log(a)}{2a}.$$

The hint is to integrate over the boundary of the domain
$\{z: \epsilon<|z|<R, \Im(z)>0\}.$

I'm not sure what to do with the integral over the outer arc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you stick to the complex-analytic technique, here is one possible solution: Choose the branch cut of complex logarithm as $[0, \infty)$ so that $\Im\log z \in [0, 2\pi)$. Then consider the function

$$ f(z) = \frac{\log^2 z}{z^2 + a^2}, $$

where $\log^2 z = (\log z)^2$ is the square of the logarithm. Then using the keyhole contour $C$ described as in Figure 1,

$\hskip{2in}$ [image: keyhole contour,]

$\hskip{1in}$ **Figure 1.** Image from @Daniel Fischer♦'s answer in [this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644927/complex-analysis-and-residue-theorem).

we find that

\begin{align*}
\oint_{C} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z
&= 2\pi i \left( \underset{z=ia}{\operatorname{Res}} f(z) + \underset{z=-ia}{\operatorname{Res}} f(z) \right) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{a} \left( \left(\log a + \frac{i\pi}{2} \right)^2 - \left(\log a + \frac{3i\pi}{2} \right)^2 \right) \\
&= \frac{2\pi^3}{a} - \frac{2\pi^2 i \log a}{a}. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

On the other hand, shrinking the inner circle $\gamma$ to the origin and letting the outer circle $\Gamma$ to the infinity, it follows that

$$ \oint_{C} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z \xrightarrow[\substack{\gamma \to 0 \\ \Gamma \to \infty}]{} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log^2 x}{x^2 + a^2} \, \mathrm{d}x - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\log x + 2\pi i)^2}{x^2 + a^2} \, \mathrm{d}x. \tag{2} $$

Comparing imaginary parts of $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$, it follows that

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log x}{x^2 + a^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi \log a}{2a}. $$

Comment: Why $\log(-ia)=\log(a)+\frac{3i\pi}{2}$? It could also have been $\log(-ia)=\log(a)-\frac{\pi}{2}$. But the latter doesn't give the required answer.

Comment: @am_11235... That follows from the choice of the branch cut of the complex logarithm as mentioned in the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

Take these lines as a long comment and not an answer, but the integral is trivial to compute through real-analytic techniques. For any $a>0$ we have:

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x/a)}{a^2+x^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{1+x^2}=\color{red}{0} $$
since the substitution $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$ gives $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{1+x^2}\,dx = -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{1+x^2}\,dx $.
On the other hand,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(a)}{a^2+x^2}\,dx = \frac{\log a}{a}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi\log a}{2a}}.$$

If you want to use contour integration, you may take a semicircular contour in the right half-plane with three bulges around $z=0$ (singularity for $\log z$) and $z=\pm i a$ (singularities for $\frac{1}{z^2+a^2}$), then apply the residue theorem. The integral over the outer arc is vanishing as $R\to +\infty$ since it is bounded by $\frac{2\pi\log R}{R}$ in absolute value for any $R$ big enough.

Comment: For future readers: this doesn't seem like quite the correct contour to take for this type of problem -- the one described has an arc along the imaginary axis, whereas what you probably want is an arc along the real axis (unless there is a nice symmetry under $z\mapsto iz$). A standard keyhole contour can also be used.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that the real part of $f (z)= \frac {\log (z)}{z^2+a^2}$ is symmetric along the origin. Then $$Re \int_{-R}^{R}f (z)dz=2\int_{0}^{R}f (x)dx$$ Now we close the contour by making a semicircle of radius $R $ along the positive imaginary axis and take the limit as $R \to \infty  $. So $$\int_{\gamma}\frac {\log(z)}{z^2+a^2}dz=\int_{-R}^{R} \frac {\log(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx+\int_{\gamma'}\frac { \log(z)}{z^2+a^2}dz$$ Where $\gamma'$ is the top part of the semicircle.  By the Estimation Lemma the top integral is bounded as $$\left|\int_{\gamma'}\frac {\log(z)}{z^2+a^2}dz \right| \le \pi\frac { \sqrt {(\log^2(R)+\pi^2)}}{R} $$ which vanishes as $R \to \infty $. Now since the value of the real integral is the only contribution to the contour integral we apply the Residue Theorem $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {\log(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx= \pi \frac {\log(a)+i\pi/2}{a}$$ But since we are not integrating over the branch cut in $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {\log (x)}{x^2+a^2}dx$$ and the real part is symmetric we can conclude $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac { \log(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx=\pi \frac { \log(a)}{2a}$$

Comment: This is much concise than mine. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Since the OP requests evaluation by contour integration, we proceed accordingly.

We begin by analyzing the contour integral $I$ as given by

$$I=\oint_C \frac{\log^2(z)}{z^2+a^2}\,dz$$

where $C$ is the classical "keyhole" contour with the "keyhole" aligned with the branch cut taken along the non-negative real axis.

Then, we have using the residue theorem

$$\begin{align}
I&=2\pi i \left(\frac{(\log(a)+i\pi/2)^2}{2ia}+\frac{(\log(a)+i3\pi/2)^2}{-2ia}\right)\\\\
&=-i 2\pi^2 \frac{\log(a)}{a}+\frac{2\pi^3}{a} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

We also have

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\log^2(x)}{x^2+a^2}\,dx+\int_\infty^0 \frac{(\log(x)+i2\pi)^2}{x^2+a^2}\,dx\\\\
&=i4\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^2+a^2}\,dx+4\pi^2 \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\,dx\\\\
&=-i4\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^2+a^2}\,dx+ \frac{2\pi^3 }{a} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Now, set real and imaginary parts of $(2)$ and $(3)$ equal to arrive at the result

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^2+a^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi \log(a)}{2a}}$$

Comment: Can it be done by real methods?

Comment: @zz20s Yes, of course it can be evaluated using real analysis only.  The OP requested specifically for a way forward that uses contour integration.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution $x=at$ gives:

$$\int_0^{\infty}  \frac{\log(x)dx}{x^2+a^2} dx=\frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(at)}{1+t^2} dt$$

$$=\frac{1}{a} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log t +\log a}{1+t^2} dt$$

Note

$$\int_0^{\infty}  \frac{\log(x)dx}{x^2+1}=0$$

This can be proved with the substitution $x=\frac{1}{u}$

Comment: I'm looking for an answer that uses contour integration.