# contour integral for $\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^2+a^2}dx$

Tags: contour-integration

> Prove using contour integration that $$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2+a^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2a}\ln a$$

I used the substitution $x=e^t$ to transform the integral to $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{te^t}{e^{2t}+a^2}dt$$ Now it is easier for integrands involving exponential terms using rectangular contour in upper half plane, and I have successfully evaluated the integral by this method. But without transforming, if I require to evaluate the integral directly, the $\ln$ term gives a branch point around $x=0$ and a branch cut along positive $x$-axis. So I chose $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{(\ln z)^2}{z^2+a^2}$ and a contour accordingly as below : [image]

Now integral around smaller contour and outer contour is $0$ and the poles are $ia$ and $-ia$. So the integral becomes $$\int_0^\infty \frac{(\ln x)^2}{x^2+a^2}dx+\int_\infty^0 \frac{(\ln x+2i\pi)^2}{x^2+a^2}dx=2\pi i\bigg(\frac{\ln^2(ia)}{2ia}+\frac{\ln^2(-ia)}{-2ia}\bigg)=\frac{2i\pi^2\ln a}{a} \\ \implies -4i\pi\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2+a^2}dx+4\pi^2\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{2i\pi^2\ln a}{a} \\ \implies \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2+a^2}dx=-\frac{\pi}{2a}\ln a \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \ \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}=0$$ which is absurd. Where am I going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why is the integral around the inner and outer contour zero?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/290200/631742

Comment: The above link has no connection with particularly what I've asked.

Comment: @am_11235... No, but it is the same integral so I thought it might be interesting to other readers of this post

Comment: Actually, I think this answers your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826381/evaluate-int-0-infty-frac-logxdxx2a2-using-contour-integration

Comment: Everything is alright, but they have taken residue at $z=-ia$ as $\ln a+\frac{3\pi i}{2}$.  Why the argument has to be $\frac{3\pi}{2}$? Whence it could also become $\ln a-\frac{i\pi}{2}$?