# Simplify result of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

It is quite easy to show that (by using residue theorem) $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}dx = \frac{2 \pi i^{1+2/n}}{n(e^{2 \pi i / n} - 1)} $$ for $$n \ge 2$$

Is there any possibility to simplify $$\frac{2 \pi i^{1+2/n}}{n(e^{2 \pi i / n} - 1)}$$
or it is best result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of $i^{2/n}$, it's probably better to write $e^{\pi i/n}$. Then you might notice that $$\frac{2i e^{\pi i/n}}{e^{2\pi i/n}-1} = \frac{2i}{(e^{2\pi i/n}-1)e^{-\pi i/n}} = \frac{2i}{e^{\pi i/n} - e^{-\pi i/n}} = \frac{1}{\sin \frac{\pi}{n}}.$$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the integral $\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\ln x}{1+x^n}}$ using complex analysis](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269081/calculating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-ln-x1xn-using-complex-an)

Answer (score 7):

$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^n}=\frac\pi n\cdot\csc\frac\pi n$ . This can be easily shown by letting $t=\dfrac1{1+x^n}$ , then recognizing the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, and then employing [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties).

Answer (score 3):

Let $y = x^n$, then $\displaystyle dx = \frac{y^{(1-n)/n}}{n} dy $ and the integral changes into 
$$\frac 1 n \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y^{\frac 1 n - 1}}{1+y} dy = \frac{1}{n} \frac{\pi}{\sin \left( \frac \pi n  \right)}$$
the integral is evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37372/2199).