# Complex integration f

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Prove that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{1+t^{n}}=\frac{\pi}{n}\csc\frac{\pi}{n}$$
Please help,I don't have a clue

Comment: Are you familiar with the Residue theorem ? Try the "pizza slice" contour of angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$. Try to show that the function tends to zero on the circular part of the contour as the radius tends to infinity.

Comment: I think this has been asked before. Did you search the site?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781186/simplify-result-of-int-0-infty-frac11xndx

Comment: I've informed the moderators.

Comment: @M.G I think you can vote to close it instead. After 5 votes, it will be closed.