# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^{2017}}$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^{2017}}$$

I have splitted the integral as:

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1+x^{2017}}+\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^{2017}}=I_1+I_2$$

where $$I_2=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^{2017}}$$ For $I_2$ i used substitution $x=\frac{1}{v}$ then we get

$$I_2=\int_{1}^{0}\frac{-v^{2015}\:dv}{1+v^{2017}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2015}\:dx}{1+x^{2017}}$$  hence

$$I=I_1+I_2=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1+x^{2015})\:dx}{1+x^{2017}}$$

Any clue here?

Comment: There must be an answer in the site for $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^a} \text{d} x$$

Comment: @Ghartal [Related question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781186/simplify-result-of-int-0-infty-frac11xndx) It seems like the answer is $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^a} \text{d} x=\frac{\pi}{a}\csc\left(\frac \pi {a}\right)$$

Comment: Aha! There you go!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just a particular case of a well-known identity, proved by Lucian here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781186/simplify-result-of-int-0-infty-frac11xndx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: after the hint above we get $$\frac{\pi  \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{2017}\right)}{2017}$$

Comment: @JohnDoe: I was not certain about that, it is not a duplicate strictly speaking, just a particular case of a broader question, so I used the custom template.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Oh, ok I see. I have chosen duplicate, since the description of that choice said "this has an answer already", which I deemed to be the case here. But I understand your choice too.